# Word(s) in a predicate, (object[?])? May you call it some phrase?

Tags: phrases, predicate

In this sentence:

> The dogs who run in the street are **especially irritable in the late afternoon.**

is the verb *are* transitive? *The dogs* is a noun phrase, the subject, argument of *are*; *who run in the street* is a relative clause. Can you analyse the function of *especially irritable in the late afternoon*? Are all these words a predicate? Can you call it a phrase (and what type of phase is it)? Or mostly a predicate that may predicate on *are*, so all those words may be called an object?

Answer (score 5):

*Are* is a copular verb, which means that *especially irritable* is a **complement to the subject**. The phrase *in the late afternoon* is an adverbial complement.

Copular verbs don't take objects. They take a complement to the subject that tells us more about the subject, it qualifies the subject. *Especially irritable* is not a new person or object in the sentence, it elaborates on our existing subject.

Some other examples:

> I am a doctor.

The word *a doctor* here is the same person as the subject *I*. It is not an object. Notice the difference:

> I saw a doctor.

Here *a doctor* is not the same person as the subject. There is no copular verb here. *Saw* is a transitive verb and *a doctor* is a direct object.

Comment: +1 I'd say that *especially irritable* is a complement to the *verb* and is predicated of the subject; syntactically it is the verb which evokes both arguments. But terminology around these things varies widely.

Comment: So *are* gets called a copular verb and requests no object. And *especially irritable in the late afternoon.* may get discerned in two bits, *especially irritable* a complement (any phrase[?]) and *in the late afternoon* an adverbial compliment. May you call these one predicate? And I guess I thought complements mostly go to verbs. It seems here a complement goes to a subject? May there seem a difference from complement to predicate maybe in like grammatical signification?

Comment: May you utilize those phrases like this? ***Especially irritable**, the dogs ran.* and maybe ***In the late afternoon**, the dogs ran.*?

Comment: No, the complements are not part of your predicate. The predicate corresponds to the verb and auxiliaries in your sentence. For example: 'He used to be a doctor.' *Used to be* is your predicate. The complements are not a part of your predicate. Complements to the subject (or simply subject complements) are used with copular verbs to modify your subject. Object complements modify your object (for example 'I find your dog *funny*' where *funny* is an object complement. Adverbial complements modify your verb. Finally, you have prepositional complements. These complements begin with a preposition.